# Generate combinations of integers by least sum

Tags: python, sum, combinations, primes

My issue stems from generating unique combinations of a very large sorted list of prime numbers choose 5, but I need the combinations to be returned such that the combinations with the smallest sums are returned first. The python `itertools.combinations()` function returns the numbers, increasing the final one until it reaches the end of the iterable object before increasing the next one, etc. This is unsuitable for my project because the sum will continue to increase until it reaches the final element of my set of primes, at which point the sum will drop before increasing again.

For instance, if I have a small set of primes `{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29}`, I would need the combinations to be returned in this order:

```
    (2, 3, 5, 7, 11)    sum = 28
    (2, 3, 5, 7, 13)    sum = 30
    (2, 3, 5, 7, 17)    sum = 34
    (2, 3, 5, 11, 13)   sum = 34
    (2, 3, 5, 7, 19)    sum = 36
    (2, 3, 7, 11, 13)   sum = 36
    (2, 3, 5, 11, 17)   sum = 38
    (2, 5, 7, 11, 13)   sum = 38
    (3, 5, 7, 11, 13)   sum = 39
    (2, 3, 5, 7, 23)    sum = 40
    (2, 3, 5, 11, 19)   sum = 40
    (2, 3, 5, 13, 17)   sum = 40
    (2, 3, 7, 11, 17)   sum = 40
    (2, 3, 5, 13, 19)   sum = 42
    (2, 3, 7, 11, 19)   sum = 42
    (2, 3, 7, 13, 17)   sum = 42
    (2, 5, 7, 11, 17)   sum = 42
    ...
```

The order of two sets with the same sum doesn't matter, just as long as a set with a greater sum is not returned by a generator before a set with a lesser sum. The set of primes I'm working with contains approximately 100,000 elements, meaning simply generating all combinations and sorting them is incredibly infeasible, as it would require space for 83,325,000,291,662,500,020,000 tuples of 5 integers each. Furthermore, each element in the returned tuple of combinations must be unique; there can be no repeated integers.  Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way to generate combinations ordered by increasing sum of indexes]
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16737068/efficient-way-to-generate-combinations-ordered-by-increasing-sum-of-indexes/16741491#16741491)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of generating combinations and summing them, try it the other way round - given a sequence of sums, generate combinations for each sum:

```
# some primes for tesing
primes = [2]
x = 3
while x < 100000:
    if all(x % p for p in primes):
        primes.append(x)
    x += 2

# main code

def find(tsum, tlen):

    def _find(tsum, tlen, path, idx):
        if tlen <= 0:
            if tsum == 0:
                yield path
            return
        while True:
            p = primes[idx]
            if p > tsum:
                return
            for f in _find(tsum - p, tlen - 1, path + [p], idx + 1):
                yield f
            idx += 1

    return _find(tsum, tlen, [], 0)

for s in range(1001, 1002): # just for testing, should be range(28, max possible sum)
    for comb in find(s, 5):
        print s, comb
```

This is far from ideal in terms of performance, but still quite fast on my machine.

Comment: I would guess this is in principle the best way to do it for a dense set like the primes numbers, where you can expect a lot of solutions for any given sum.  But you should pick and test the last number in a tuple without search, and handle 2 specially, as its presence determines whether the sum is even or odd.

Comment: @starblue: sure, there are many possible optimizations, but I wanted to keep the code simple, to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much space this would need, so better try it with a smaller set of primes first.

- Have an array/a list of the primes, sorted in ascending order.
- Keep a priority queue of index-quintuples, with the sum of the corresponding primes as the key/weight/priority/whaddayacallit, initially filled with the quintuple `(0,1,2,3,4)` of weight `2+3+5+7+11 = 28`.
- While the queue is not empty,

  1. get the quintuple with smallest sum from the queue, say `(a, b, c, d, e, f)` (remove it, of course).
  2. insert the direct successors of it into the queue, the successors are those of

     - `(a+1,b,c,d,e)`
     - `(a,b+1,c,d,e)`
     - `(a,b,c+1,d,e)`
     - `(a,b,c,d+1,e)`
     - `(a,b,c,d,e+1)`

     which are strictly ascending and have last component smaller than length of prime list
  3. yield the previously gotten quintuple

Comment: Assuming this is tested with a list of primes beginning with `(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19...)`, the first tuple that should be returned would be `(2,3,5,7,11)`, which would have indices `(0,1,2,3,4)`. Unless I'm misunderstanding your answer, wouldn't adding the successors by incrementing each index by one cause multiples of a single value to appear in each tuple? I just updated my answer to specify that the combinations are without replacement, in case it was ambiguous in that respect.

Comment: @matt18224 Yes, you need a priority queue with only unique elements. Depending on the implementation of the PQ, you need to take care of that yourself by having a set of tuples already in the PQ and only adding the children if they are not yet in it (you can remove each tuple from the set when it is popped from the queue). But when you let it generate a lot of tuples, the queue gets rather large, so one would have to delay putting tuples into it in some way. Not sure if there is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**IF it can help you**, here is a program in C that **almost** generates combinations of integers by a least sum. The integers must be given in ascending order. This progam is inherited from the other program in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16241278/2675154):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int v[100], stack[100];
int sp,i,j,k,n,g,s;
int main()
{
    printf("Dimension of V:");
    scanf( "%d",&n);
    //Input numbers
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
        printf("V[%d]=",i);
        scanf( "%d",&g);
        v[i]=g;
    }
    printf("subset number:");
    scanf( "%d",&k);
    printf("running...\n");
    j=0;
    s=0;
    sp=-1;
    while(1) {
        // stack ones until stack overflow
        while(sp<n-1 && j<k && n-sp>k-j)  {
            j=j+1;
            sp=sp+1;
            stack[sp]=1;
            s=s+v[sp];
            if(j==k) {
                for (i=0 ; i<=sp ; i++) if (stack[i]==1) printf("%2d ",v[i]);
                printf("sum=%d\n",s);
            }
        }
        // unstack all the zeros until top of stack is equal one
        while (stack[sp]==0 && sp>=0) sp=sp-1;
        // if Bottom of stack is reached then stop
        if (sp<0) break;
        // set top of stack from one to zero
        stack[sp]=0;
        s=s-v[sp];
        j=j-1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```